# Getting last insert id from MySQL stored in Python

Tags: python, stored-procedures, mysql-connector

I am using the MySQL connector in Python (3.9 on Windows) to call a stored procedure that does an insert, but when I try to get the last insert ID I get 0, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

What I am calling:

```
cursor.callproc(procedure_name, params_list)
print('last id:', cursor.lastrowid)
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE add_image_path()
BEGIN

INSERT into ImagePath values(0, "test");

END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cursor.lastrowid` is set from `mysql_insert_id()` instead of `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

You can manually set it from `LAST_INSERT_ID()`:

```py
cursor.callproc(procedure_name, params_list)
cursor.execute('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()'))  # Add this
cursor.lastrowid = cursor.fetchone()[0]     # Add this
print('last id:', cursor.lastrowid)
```

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-insert-id.html:

> `mysql_insert_id()` returns `0` following a `CALL` statement for a stored procedure that generates an `AUTO_INCREMENT` value because in this case `mysql_insert_id()` applies to `CALL` and not the statement within the procedure. Within the procedure, you can use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` at the SQL level to obtain the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value.
>
> The reason for the differences between `LAST_INSERT_ID()` and `mysql_insert_id()` is that `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is made easy to use in scripts while `mysql_insert_id()` tries to provide more exact information about what happens to the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column.